# Sql transformation to prevent target table truncate in informatica power centre

Tags: plsql, informatica

I have come across a scenario where I need to truncate and load data in oracle tables from flat files without any logic . But when source is not available target is getting truncated which is not a valid thing.
Need help to do this Sql transformation informatica so if input field from source do not have value then it do not truncate and if it have value then truncate and load using query mode
Please help me to write a code in such way

I am trying below code but it is throwing error

If: input field is null then
Null;
Else
Truncate table target table
End if ;

Comment: What error, you might include that.
Also have a look and this link: https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-if/ 

You're not including enough of your script to let us understand the problem you're facing. I mean your last line which is the closest to code doesn't look like pl sql.

Please mark your code with the code tag {} it will help formatting and if not enough, please structure the code so it is nice to read and comment on

Answer (score 0):

There's number of ways to tacke this, I'll just highlight:

1. Create additional session that will try and read data and discard all the results with a `Filter Transformation` set to `FALSE`
2. Even better, but more advanced solution: Use a partitioned target table. Use a temp table to insert the data and in your Post-SQL check the count in the temp table and `switch partition` if temp table is not empty.